# Services Using com.apple.geod

Tags: macos

I blocked the `com.apple.geod` process with my software firewall but after 2 days of non-stop 1 second attempts I just `pkill`'ed it.

I want to know what services are using this so I can disable them from running `com.apple.geod` if possible.

Edit:
Scratch the `pkill`.  That didn't keep it away for long.

Comment: it's Location services - prefs >Security & Privacy > Privacy; but I'm not sure that switching that off will stop the process entirely.

Comment: @Tetsujin Disabling Location Services did not stop it... Someone really wants those datapoints

Comment: Apple (as said in the Software Beta Program Licence Agreement) explicitly tells users that it reports the location of the device once daily. If the process is stopped, it would restart it and it would be deemed as a hang.

Comment: I moved the files to different names and killed the processes. They haven't come back yet.

Comment: @jbg What files?

Comment: The executables that you want to prevent from running. If you use `ps ax` you can see the paths to the executable files, just move them to a different name (as root) and then kill the processes. They won't be able to launch any more because they don't exist in the location they're supposed to exist in.

Comment: I should point out that applied in general, this advice is a very quick way to render your macOS installation unusable. For `geod` specifically though, the impact seems to be minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making an exhaustive list of all processes that call a specific API or process would be technically challenging even for one single release point of MacOS. You would either need access to the source code of all of MacOS and every single app - both first party and third party - or you would need to debug/reverse engineer all processes as they run and expose those calls.

The application Little Snitch does that for the network stack - so you might have better luck just blocking network access to Apple servers rather than trying to block the calls to the service locally.

Even if you were to process all the geo location aspects on developer.apple.com - it's widely used - far greater than just the Core Location API - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation.

- Weather
- Calendar
- Address Book
- Maps
- Siri
- iCloud (finding the best data center to route uploads)
- Store (which geographic region should your content be)
- Time Zone and Night Shift
- Safari location

Comment: I always use Little Snitch.  Good advice.

Comment: Conveniently, those are all things I want to block.